# ExpressionEngine: Image tag in Rich Text Area results in Error/404 page

Tags: expressionengine, richtext

Recently launched a website using ExpressionEngine as the CMS, however have run into an issue, whenever the  tag is used and you click "save" to publish an article it results in a 404 pages, no idea why this would happen, any ideas?

I get the following debug info:

```
(0.000014 / 4.04MB) - Begin Template Processing -
(0.000985 / 4.08MB) URI: admin.php
(0.001007 / 4.08MB) Path.php Template: /
(0.001027 / 4.08MB) Retrieving Template
(0.001042 / 4.08MB) Parsing Template URI
(0.005163 / 4.26MB) Template group and template not found, showing 404 page
(0.005190 / 4.26MB) Retrieving Template from Database: /
(0.006250 / 4.27MB) Template Found
(0.006988 / 4.27MB) Retrieving Template from File
(0.007293 / 4.26MB) Template Type: 404
(0.007322 / 4.27MB) Parsing Site Variables
```

Comment: Want to move this to the EE StackExchange site? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a hosting issue, mod_security needed to be turned off…